# How to expand detached data disk in Azure RM

Tags: azure, azure-storage

This link describes how to expand attached VM OS or data disks in an Azure resource group. I want to know how can I extend a detached data disk so that I could perform this action without restarting the machine. Is that achievable?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-expand-os-disk/

Comment: You should post this to ServerFault - not a programming question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon if the answer is programming related, such as the one I provided here about using PowerShell commands, are we still considering that not to be programming related? Asking in all seriousness and not sarcastically.

Comment: I saw this more of an infrastructure question, as in "can it even be done." And didn't see it as a ps-specific question, but yeah I'd say it's valid from a PowerShell perspective, though in general, this is the type of infra-related question that would be relevant on ServerFault (and the logical place to seek such info, for future generations).

Comment: @DavidMakogon understood. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `Get-AzureDisk` PowerShell command to obtain a reference to the unattached disk. From there you can call `Update-AzureDisk` to increase the size of the disk.

Two notes which you may already know; you can't shrink a disk (without recreating it from the underlying blob) once you increase its size and generally you should avoid putting data on an OS disk so if you need more space just add another data disk.

Comment: I tried `Get-AzureDisk` but it returns blank. Maybe because of resource manager?

Comment: What are you using to specify the disk you want? If you run Get-AzureDisk | Where-Object {$_.AttachedTo -eq $Null} does it return all unattached disk?